# Problema con asignación django

Tags: django, django-forms

tengo un problema con Django y la forma de mostrar esta información, al mostrar formulario en si no tengo problemas, pero este tuve que hacerlo de esta manera y me da problemas ya que necesito que cada acción clave cuente con su nota respectiva.

Así esta el modelo que estoy usando
Models.py:

```
class Evaluacion(models.Model):
Estado = models.CharField(max_length=50, validators=[RegexValidator(regex=r'^[a-zA-Z]' )])
Fase = models.CharField(max_length=50, validators=[RegexValidator(regex=r'^[a-zA-Z]' )])
ComentarioCalibrador = models.CharField(max_length=80,  null=True, blank=True, validators=[RegexValidator(regex=r'^[a-zA-Z]' )])
FechaEvaluacion = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
ComentarioEvaluador = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True,validators=[RegexValidator(regex=r'^[a-zA-Z]' )])
AutoEvaluacion = models.IntegerField( null=True, blank=True, validators=[RegexValidator(regex=r'^[0-9]')])
IdEmpleado = models.ForeignKey(Empleado, on_delete=CASCADE, default=1)

def __str__(self):
    return self.Fase

class PlanAccion(models.Model):
Accion = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True, validators=[RegexValidator(regex=r'^[a-zA-Z]' )])
Medicion = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True, validators=[RegexValidator(regex=r'^[a-zA-Z]' )])
IdEvaluacion = models.ForeignKey(Evaluacion, on_delete=CASCADE, default=1)

def __str__(self):
    return self.Accion
```

---

Así estan los formularios de ambos modelos
Forms.py:

```
class EvaluacionForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Evaluacion
    fields = '__all__'
    widgets = {
        'ComentarioEvaluador': forms.Textarea(
            attrs = {
                'class':'form-control',
                'placeholder':'Ingrese una observacion',
            }
        )
    }
class AccionesForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = AccionClave        
    fields = ['Descripcion', 'IdCompetencia','Calificacion']
    labels = {
        'Descripcion':'Descripción',
        'IdCompetencia':'Competencia',
        'Calificacion':'',
    }
    help_texts = { 
        'Descripcion': ('No puede estar en blanco'),
    }
    widgets = {
        'Descripcion': forms.Textarea(
            attrs = {

                'class':'form-control',
                'placeholder':'Ingrese descripción',
            }
        ),
        'IdCompetencia': forms.Select(
            attrs = {
                'class':'form-select'
            }
        ),
        'Calificacion': forms.Select(
            attrs = {
                'class':'form-select'
            },
            choices = [
                (1,1),
                (2,2),
                (3,3),
                (4,4),
                (5,5),
                (6,6),
                (7,7),
            ]
        ),
    }
```

---

Esto tengo en views
Views.py

```
def evaluador_formulario2(request, id):
evaluaciones = get_object_or_404(Evaluacion, id=id)
competencias = Competencia.objects.all()
accionclaves = AccionClave.objects.all()

data = {
    'empleados': Empleado.objects.get(Nombre = evaluaciones.IdEmpleado.Nombre),
    'competencias':competencias,
    'accionclaves':accionclaves,
    'page': 'Formulario',
    'titulo': 'Formulario',
    'form': EvaluacionForm(instance = evaluaciones),
    'form2': AccionesForm(instance=evaluaciones),
}

if request.method == 'POST':
    formulario = EvaluacionForm(data=request.POST, instance=evaluaciones)
    if formulario.is_valid():
        form = formulario.cleaned_data.get("ComentarioEvaluador")
        evaluacionid = Evaluacion.objects.get(id = id)
        accionid = AccionClave.objects.get(id = id)
        evaluacionid.ComentarioEvaluador = form
        evaluacionid.Estado = "Pendiente"
        evaluacionid.save()
        accionid.save()
        messages.success(request,'Guardado el plan de acción')
        return redirect(to="evaluadorEvaluacion")
    else:
        data["form"] = formulario
return render(request, "evaluador/evaluadorFormulario2.html", data)
```

---

Esto tengo en mi vista html, ya que son tablas distintas no puedo utilizar el mismo formulario y tube que hacerlo iterando ya que dependiendo del perfil se muestran las competencias y dependiendo las competencias se muestran las acciones claves.

HTML:

```
{% for competencia in competencias %}
                    {% if empleados.IdPerfil == competencia.IdPerfil %}
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-header" style="background-color:#f3c53f;text-align:center;">
                                <a class="card-link" data-toggle="collapse" style="color:white">
                                    <h5>Competencia: {{ competencia.NombreCompetencia }}</h5>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" data-parent="#accordion">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                                            <b>Definicion:</b>
                                            {{ competencia.Definicion }}
                                            <br><br>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="row" style="text-align:center">
                                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                                <h5><b>Acciones clave</b><h5>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-2">
                                                <h5><b>Calificación</b><h5>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                                            {% for accionclave in accionclaves %}
                                                {% if competencia.NombreCompetencia == accionclave.IdCompetencia.NombreCompetencia %}
                                                    <div class="row">
                                                        <p>
                                                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                                                {{ accionclave.Descripcion }}
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="col-sm-2">
                                                                {{ form2.Calificacion }}
                                                            </div>
                                                        </p>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <hr>
                                                {% endif %}
                                            {% endfor %}
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
```

---

Así se vería:
[image: Vista del formulario]